# Can't open any file with emacs-live configuration on OSX

Tags: macos, git, emacs, clojure, customization

I saw the `emacs-live` demo by Sam Aaron with overtone. I went to the GitHub repository, got his `.emacs.d` setup and replaced my setup with it by deleting an existing `.emacs` file.

Everything seems good, I have most of the `emacs-live` features but I can't seem to open any existing file.

Every time I do  a <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> and select a file, I get this message:

```
"Searching for program: no such file or directory, git "
```

[image: ido-find-file prompt]

[image: error message]

Also, it loads a lot of packages and takes time to initialize and gets stuck at a message that reads:

```
Zoning... (zone-pgm-putz-with-case)
```

[image: loading packages]

[image: message it gets stuck at]

I am new to Emacs, any idea what must be going wrong here?

---

**EDIT 1**:

I have Git installed on my system!

Here is the repo that I used: https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live

---

**EDIT 2**:

Output from the debugger:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "git")                                        
  call-process("git" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup")                                                                
  apply(call-process "git" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup"))                                                        
  process-file("git" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup")                                                                
  apply(process-file "git" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup"))                                                        
  (progn (apply (function process-file) magit-git-executable nil (list t nil) nil (append magit-git-standard-options args)) (if (= (point-m$
  (unwind-protect (progn (apply (function process-file) magit-git-executable nil (list t nil) nil (append magit-git-standard-options args))$
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (apply (function process-file) magit-git-executable nil (list t nil)$
  (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (apply (functio$
  magit-git-string("rev-parse" "--show-cdup")                                                                                               
  (let* ((default-directory (file-name-as-directory cwd)) (cdup (magit-git-string "rev-parse" "--show-cdup"))) (if cdup (progn (file-name-a$
  (progn (let* ((default-directory (file-name-as-directory cwd)) (cdup (magit-git-string "rev-parse" "--show-cdup"))) (if cdup (progn (file$
  (if (file-directory-p cwd) (progn (let* ((default-directory (file-name-as-directory cwd)) (cdup (magit-git-string "rev-parse" "--show-cdu$
  magit-get-top-dir()                                                                                                                       
  (and magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode (not auto-revert-mode) (not auto-revert-tail-mode) (not global-auto-revert-mode) (magit-get-top-dir)) 
  (if (and magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode (not auto-revert-mode) (not auto-revert-tail-mode) (not global-auto-revert-mode) (magit-get-top-d$
  magit-maybe-turn-on-auto-revert-mode()                                                                                                    
  run-hooks(find-file-hook)                                                                                                                 
  after-find-file(nil t)                                                                                                                    
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer access.clj> "~/Desktop/hulk/src/core/models/access.clj" nil nil "~/Desktop/hulk/src/core/models/access.clj"$
  find-file-noselect("/Users/amogh/Desktop/hulk/src/core/models/access.clj" nil nil)                                                        
  ido-file-internal(selected-window)                                                                                                        
  ido-find-file()                                                                                                                           
  call-interactively(ido-find-file nil nil)
```

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the first error by installing [Git](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) on your system. Also: It would be great if you could provide a link to the GitHub repository containing the configuration you are trying to load.

Comment: The "Zoning..." message is because `zone` has been invoked (the part in parenthesis tells you which of the available `zone-programs` is in effect). The display is almost certainly doing something a bit funky at the time. You can call it yourself with `M-x zone`.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar Which command is `C-x C-f` bound to? Do `C-h k` `C-x C-f` to find out. (By default, `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file` which does not depend on `git`.)

Comment: Type `C-h v exec-path RET` in Emacs, and `which git` from a regular shell, and check whether the path for the latter appears in the results for the former. (Ooh... looks like emacs-live rebinds `C-h`; that's not too friendly. You'll need to use `<f1> v` instead of `C-h v`.)

Comment: @itsjeyd its says ido-find-file is the command!

Comment: The path is ("/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /Users/amogh/bin /usr/local/sbin /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/")

and which git gives "/usr/bin/git". what must be wrong now ?

Comment: Also I am not using bash, I use fish shell. Does that make a difference ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar What's the output of `M-x getenv RET PATH RET`? Also, are you getting the "no such file or directory" error only for files that are part of a `git` repository or does it come up when you try to open a file that's *not* part of a repo as well?

Comment: Okay, it looks like that's a proper error, so please use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to enable debugging, then trigger the error, and paste the full stack trace into the question. It still sounds very much like a path issue of some sort, but the stack ought to be useful. Also mention which version of Emacs you are using, please (`M-x emacs-version`).

Comment: I know it would be nice for the original poster to figure out what is wrong with his `$PATH`.  But I though I should point out that there are only 17 references across 9 files for the term `"git"` (**using quotations marks in the search**), so one option would be to use an absolute path and of course make sure that the program git is installed.  But, be precise when modifying, as not all of the 17 references necessarily need an executable.  For example, `define-ibuffer-column git-status` is **NOT** one of them.

Comment: On OSX, I use this:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))` for LaTeX stuff.  The original poster could probably just use the same thing, but substituting `":/usr/texbin"` with `":/usr/bin"` and that may resolve the issue.  If the original poster uses TexLive also, then just append it using colons -- e.g., `":/usr/texbin:/usr/bin"`

Comment: @itsjeyd: I can't open any file by directly saying. emacs path/to/file.
It starts in scratch mode.
even if I do a C-x C-f and  chose the file, it still goes to scratch.
However, I can find the file in the buffer, and open it using Cx-C-b.

Comment: @phils: I am using emacs 24.3

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, sorry. The C code for `call_process` certainly uses the `exec-path` variable in its call to `openp`, so I *assume* it should find `git` given the values you showed earlier, but I'm unsure of the specifics of how this stuff operates. Could you repeat the test, and this time (in the debugger) type `e` to evaluate, and then `exec-path` `RET` to establish whether it's being overridden at that point? Failing that, I can only agree with checking the `PATH` environment variable too (have you tried rimero's answer?), and checking the file permissions for `git`.

Comment: If you don't find a solution here, raise this in the emacs-live github issue queue.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar Does that mean the original problem you had when opening files is gone? If it is you might want to consider posting an answer describing what you ended up doing to fix it (and ask a different question about the problem you are facing now). If the original problem persists you should follow @phils' advice and get in touch with the `emacs-live` authors on GitHub.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar One more piece of advice to use going forward (this doesn't answer your question but I think it should be mentioned anyway): *Ask yourself what exactly you are trying to achieve, and then assess your level of knowledge about the technologies involved in achieving it:* (1) Do you want to learn Emacs? If that's your *main* goal you might be better off starting with vanilla Emacs (instead of blindly using a starter kit), learning about its features, and slowly adding bits and pieces of configuration that seem useful to you over time, as you become familiar with it. (contd.)

Comment: (2) Do you want to make music with Overtone? If that's your goal, are you already familiar with Clojure and SuperCollider? Are you familiar with audio synthesis in general? If you are not, you might want to consider working on learning about these things first. As far as I know, Emacs is not a hard dependency of Overtone; you can use other editors to modify the code you write. *The point is:* You will save yourself a lot of frustration by taking one step at a time, and breaking up the learning process into more manageable pieces.

Comment: @itsjeyd: The problem was never not being able to open the file. The git error still appears. the file was always in the buffer but then I had to go to the buffer and select it.

I just needed a decent emacs setup that had auto completes, dropdowns, in-line REPL facilities irrespective of whether I want to play music or not.
I know a bit of clojure, have spend 6-7 months with it on a web application with basic emacs that had clojure mode and paredit.
Whats wrong in me trying to get something better ?
If I can't I always have the option to go back.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).